# Amadeus Hotel Search API (Self-Service APIs) with GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, amadeus

I'm using Amadeus Hotel Search API which is one of the their Self Service APIs for my React.js app.
With deployment of Cloud Functions in GCP, there is a problem.

1. Test deployment: this is working well.

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");

exports.helloWorld = onRequest({maxInstances: 10}, (request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello World!!");
});
```

However, second one is not working.

2. Deployment of function with Amadeus Hotel Search API

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const Amadeus = require("amadeus");

const amadeus = new Amadeus({
  clientId: process.env.AMADEUS_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AMADEUS_CLIENT_SECRET,
});

exports.hotelOffersSearch = onRequest({maxInstances: 10}, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await amadeus.shopping.hotelOffersSearch.get({
      hotelIds: "RTPAR001",
      adults: "2",
    });
    console.log(response.data);
    res.status(200).send(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

Below is a part of error message when i tried to deploy second one in command.

> functions: creating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function
> hotelOffersSearch(us-central1)... Could not create or update Cloud Run
> service hotelofferssearch, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision
> 'hotelofferssearch-00001-tox' is not ready and cannot serve traffic.
> The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port
> defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this
> revision might contain more information.

And, If I try a request on command, it's working well like this.

[image]

What's wrong with me?
I think, it's about Amadeus api issue because first test version was deployed successfully.

I'm a beginner, so please explain it in an easy way to understand.

Deployment of HTTP request function in Cloud Functions with Amadeus api

Comment: Does Cloud Logging for the Function show anything? I am not sure what `Amadeus()` is performing behind the scenes when setting up the client. Try moving that code into your function's onRequest() try block.